# FPDF Print Orientation

Tags: fpdf

I will create an PDF envelope/label file (size 220 x 110 mm) with FPDF.
I know how to orientate from portrait to landscape.

```
$pdf = new FPDF('L','mm',array(110,220));
$pdf->AddPage('L');
```

On my screen I will see an envelope in landscape, but when I print the PDF it is supposed to print it in portrait because the envelopes are fed in portrait.

Can anyone tell me how to do that?

It is also ok if I can orient the fonts only. So that the screen shows portrait. I know it is not a beautiful solution but if it works then it is ok.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print in horizontal, add the line

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage('O');
```

If you want to print in vertical, add the line

```
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
```